# Find out apple email id from iphone activation lock

Tags: iphone, apple-id, activation-lock

Is there anyway to find out the email address attached to iphone, when iphone is currently locked to activation mode ?

I just needed to know the email address so I can reset the password. 
The person who attached the Apple ID forgot which account she was using

Comment: Something fishy here. Just how many emails can one have without remembering them? I have 4 and have no problem remembering while been 65 years old.

Comment: and even if you knew the email the rest password will be send to that email, so how would you access the email?

Answer (score 2):

How to find the AppleID

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5625

If you can't remember your Apple ID, follow these steps to look for it:

> Go to My Apple ID (appleid.apple.com) and click “Find your Apple ID”.
>
> Enter the first name, last name, current email address, and **any prior
>   email addresses that you might have used to create an Apple ID**. Apple
>   uses this information to search for Apple IDs.
>
> If no Apple IDs are found, follow the onscreen instructions to create
>   an Apple ID.
>
> If one Apple ID is found, choose whether to receive an email from
>   Apple or answer security questions. Both options will conclude by
>   asking you to reset your Apple ID password. Follow the instructions
>   provided.
>
> If multiple Apple IDs are found, select the one that matches your
>   current email address. Then choose whether to receive an email from
>   Apple or answer security questions. Both options will conclude by
>   asking you to reset your Apple ID password. Follow the instructions
>   provided.